# If $F$ is an $s$-spectrum, then what does the functor $\sum_s^n F$ mean for negative values of $n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

I have been learning motivic homotopy theory from [these notes](https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/Nordfjordeid_lectures_published.pdf) and on page 151 (page 5 of the pdf), the author uses $\sum_s^n F$ where $F$ is an $s$-spectrum. For non-negative $n$, I figured that this meant "take the smash product of $F$ with the $n$-fold smash product of $S^1_s$", but I cannot make sense of it for negative values of $n$.

Comment: Have you studied (non-motivic) stable homotopy theory before?  The passage from spaces to spectra can be thought of as "inverting the suspension".  It looks like the notes uses a version of sequential spectra, so desuspension is shifting all the spaces in one direction, roughly speaking.

Comment: @JHF Is this somehow using that $ - \wedge S^1_s$ is a quasi-isomorphism, so by negative powers, we mean apply a quasi-inverse to the spectrum?

Comment: Not really.  What do you mean by quasi-isomorphism in this context?  What is true is that suspension is an autoequivalence in the category of spectra, and hence is invertible.  Of course, this is something you need to prove when dealing with a concrete model for spectra.

Comment: @JHF Since $-\wedge S^1_s$ is an autoequivalence in the category of spectra, there is a quasi-inverse functor, which is what I thought "inverting the suspension" meant.